# Can't get a login/sign up form to work with Firebase using React Native

Tags: react-native

I've trying to authenticate a React Native sign in/up form with Firebase but it won't work. Any help will be appreciated.

I've updated npm to the latest version as I read it has worked for others but I'm still having the issue. I keep getting the 'Authentication failed' error. I have enabled email/pass authentication in the Firebase console

---

**File: app.js**

```js
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';


    import LoginCard from './src/components/LoginCard'



    const instructions = Platform.select({
      ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
      android:
        'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
        'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
    });


    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          isLoggedIn:null
        }
        this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
      }

      componentWillMount(){
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "...",
          authDomain: "...",
          databaseURL: "...",
          projectId: "authentication-...",
          storageBucket: "",
          messagingSenderId: "...",
          appId: "..."
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
          firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if(user) {
            this.setState({isLoggedIn:true})
          } else{
            this.setState({isLoggedIn:false})
          }
        })
      }
       renderContent(){
        if(!this.state.isLoggedIn){
          return <LoginCard />
        }else{
          return <Button title='Log Out' onPress = {() => firebase.auth().signOut()}></Button>
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style = {styles.header}>
              <Text style ={{fontSize:24}}>Auth</Text>
            </View>
            {this.renderContent()}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    ========LoginCard.js FILE==========

    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import React ,{Component} from 'react';
    import {Text, TextInput,View,TouchableOpacity,ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
    import Spinner from './Spinner';
    import {CirclesLoader,PulseLoader,DotsLoader} from 'react-native-indicator';`

    class LoginCard extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          email:null,
          password:null,
          error:null,
          loading:false
        }
        this.onButtonPress = this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
        this.buttonOrLoading = this.buttonOrLoading.bind(this);
      }

      onButtonPress()  {
        this.setState({error:null,loading:true})
        const {email, password} = this.state;

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
          .then(() => this.setState({error:null,loading:false}))
          .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .then(() => this.setState({error:null,loading:false}))
              .catch(() => {
                this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed',loading:false})
              })
          })
      }
      buttonOrLoading(){
        if(this.state.loading){
          return <CirclesLoader />
        }
        else return <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress = {this.onButtonPress}
        style = {styles.btn}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize:18}}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
      }
      render(){
        return (
          <View style = {styles.card}>
            <TextInput 
            style = {styles.inputField} 
            placeholder='Email' 
            onChangeText = {email => this.setState({email})}
            value = {this.state.email}
            autoCorrect = {false}/>

            <TextInput 
            style = {styles.inputField} 
            placeholder='Password'
            onChangeText = {password => this.setState({password})}
            value = {this.state.password}
            autoCorrect = {false}
            secureTextEntry = {true}/>

            <Text style= 
     {{color:'red',fontSize:12,alignSelf:'center',margin:5}}>
              {this.state.error}
            </Text>

            {this.buttonOrLoading()}
          </View>`
        );
      }
    };
```

The Login button is expected to create a new user if the email is never used before however I think the 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' method is not doing that.

Comment: You should log the error message on error while login. There are usefull information there

Comment: According to this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithemailandpassword,  the specific error code **auth/user-not-found** is thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email. So in this case, you could create a new user, for others errors codes you set the error message : **incorrect login and password**.